# Apache Beam GroupByKey() fails when running on Google DataFlow in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline using the Python SDK 2.2.0 for Apache Beam.

This pipeline is almost a typical word count: I have pairs of names in the format `("John Doe, Jane Smith", 1)`, and I'm trying to figure out how many times each pair of names appears together, like this:

```
p_collection
            | "PairWithOne" >> beam.Map(lambda pair: (', '.join(pair).encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode(), 1))
            | "GroupByKey" >> beam.GroupByKey()
            | "AggregateGroups" >> beam.Map(lambda (pair, ones): (pair, sum(ones)))
            | "Format" >> beam.Map(lambda element: {'pair': element[0], 'pair_count': element[1]})
```

When I run this code locally, with a small dataset, it works perfectly.

But when I deploy it to Google Cloud DataFlow, I get the following error:

> An exception was raised when trying to execute the workitem
>   423109085466017585 : Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py",
>   line 582, in do_work work_executor.execute() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py",
>   line 167, in execute op.start() File
>   "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 49, in
>   dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
>   def start(self): File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line
>   50, in
>   dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
>   with self.scoped_start_state: File
>   "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 65, in
>   dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
>   with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader: File
>   "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 69, in
>   dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
>   self.output(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 154, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
>   cython.cast(Receiver,
>   self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
>   cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value) File
>   "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 233, in
>   dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
>   self.output(wvalue.with_value((k, wvalue.value))) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 154, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
>   cython.cast(Receiver,
>   self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
>   cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 339, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process with
>   self.scoped_process_state: File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 340, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
>   self.dofn_receiver.receive(o) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 382, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
>   self.process(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 390, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
>   self._reraise_augmented(exn) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 415, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
>   raise File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 388, in
>   apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
>   self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 189, in
>   apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
>   self.output_processor.process_outputs( File
>   "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 480, in
>   apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
>   self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
>   cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 339, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process with
>   self.scoped_process_state: File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 340, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
>   self.dofn_receiver.receive(o) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 382, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
>   self.process(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 390, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
>   self._reraise_augmented(exn) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py",
>   line 431, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
>   raise new_exn, None, original_traceback File
>   "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 388, in
>   apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
>   self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 189, in
>   apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
>   self.output_processor.process_outputs( File
>   "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 480, in
>   apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
>   self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 84, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
>   self.update_counters_start(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 90, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start
>   self.opcounter.update_from(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 63, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from
>   self.do_sample(windowed_value) File
>   "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 81, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample
>   self.coder_impl.get_estimated_size_and_observables(windowed_value))
>   File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 730, in
>   apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
>   def get_estimated_size_and_observables(self, value, nested=False):
>   File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 739, in
>   apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
>   self._value_coder.get_estimated_size_and_observables( File
>   "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 518, in
>   apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.AbstractComponentCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
>   values[i], nested=nested or i + 1 < len(self._coder_impls)))
>   RuntimeError: KeyError: 0 [while running 'Transform/Format']

Looking [at the source code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py) of where this error pops up from, I thought it could be cause due to the fact that some of the names contain some weird encoded characters, so in a desperate act I tried using the `.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode()` you see on the code, but no luck.

Any ideas as to why this pipeline executes successfully locally, but fails on DataFlow runner?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the same position as you. Pipeline runs perfectly locally, but fails on Dataflow with the exact same RuntimeError. I'm working with NumPy arrays and the like, not text, so I'm also guessing it's something more than character encoding.

Comment: In your particular case, any reason you can't replace the `GroupByKey` and `AggregateGroups` steps with `beam.CombinePerKey(sum))`? [wordcount_minimal](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_minimal.py) follows this pattern. I'm not sure if it will make your issue go away, but it would simplify your pipeline and avoid an explicit `GroupByKey`, if that's an issue.

Alternatively, you could use `Count.PerElement` and essentially get rid of the `PairWithOne` step, too (you'd need to do the string combining, though, if you need it with that format).

Comment: @user1093967, I have no idea why, but replacing `GroupByKey` and `AggregateGroups` with `CombinePerKey(sum)` made the problem disappear! So thank you for the tip :)

Comment: @user1093967, did you make sure to add NumPy as a dependency that has to be installed on the workers? I'm just guessing here, but I've had a problem before that the dependency was installed in my lib folder, but not declared in the required_packages in my `setup.py`.

Comment: I haven't explicitly specified it as a dependency, but I don't think that's the issue, because I'm still able to run transforms that depend on NumPy on Dataflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't so much of a fix to my problem as it is avoiding the problem in the first place, but it **did** make my code run, thanks to the suggestion of user1093967 in the comments.

I just replaced the `GroupByKey` and the `AggregateGroups` by a `CombinePerKey(sum)` step and the problem didn't occur anymore.

```
p_collection
        | "PairWithOne" >> beam.Map(lambda pair: (', '.join(pair).encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode(), 1))
        | "GroupAndSum" >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
        | "Format" >> beam.Map(lambda element: {'pair': element[0], 'pair_count': element[1]})
```

I'd be happy to hear why it works, though.

Comment: Glad it worked! I don't know _why_ `GroupByKey` doesn't work (I'm getting the feeling that it's sketchy based on some old Stack Overflow answers, but it's far more likely I just don't understand how it works). All I know is that the `DirectRunner` and `DataflowRunner` implementations of `GroupByKey` are different.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, like my own, you need the intermediate grouped values, so `CombinePerKey` isn't ideal. In this more general case, you can replace `GroupByKey()` with `CombineValues(ToListCombineFn())`.

I'm not confident as to why this works while `GroupByKey` doesn't. My guess is that consuming the `_UnwindowedValues` iterable returned by `GroupByKey` like a list fails in a parallel execution environment. I was doing something like:

```
... | beam.GroupByKey()
    | beam.Map(lambda k_v: (k_v[0], foo(list(k_v[1]))))
    | ...
```

where `foo` requires the full, indexable list and is not easily composable. I'm not sure why this sort of restriction would have caused issues for you, though; `sum` can operate on an iterable.

This solution isn't ideal in that (I believe) you lose some parallelization with the `ToList` conversion. That being said, at least it's an option if anybody else faces this same issue!

Answer (score 0):

**GroupByKey** groups all elements with the same key and produces multiple PCollections. The next stage receives an Iterable collecting all elements with the same key. The important note is that this Iterable is evaluated lazily, at least when GroupByKey is executed on the Dataflow runner. This means that elements are loaded into memory on demand — when requested from the iterator.

**CombinePerKey** on the other hand, also groups all elements with the same key, but does an aggregation before emitting a single value.

```
pcollection_obj
        | "MapWithOne" >> beam.Map(lambda pair: (', '.join(pair).encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode(), 1))
        | "GroupByKeyAndSum" >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
        | "CreateDictionary" >> beam.Map(lambda element: {'pair': element[0], 'pair_count': element[1]})
```

@Hannon César I hope this answers your question.
Cheers !!