# Side inputs to WriteToBigQuery - PCollection of size 2 with more than one element accessed as a singleton view

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a **streaming** apache beam pipeline which does operations on data and writes to big query, the table name and schema of said data is within the data itself, so i am using side inputs to provide table name and schema using side_inputs for both of them.

So my pipeline code looks something like this -

```
 pipeline | "Writing to big query">>beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        schema=lambda row,schema:write_table_schema(row,schema),
        schema_side_inputs = (table_schema,),
        project=args['PROJECT_ID'],dataset=args['DATASET_ID'],
        table = lambda row,table_name:write_table_name(row,table_name),table_side_inputs=(table_name,) ,ignore_unknown_columns=args['ignore_unknown_columns'], 
        additional_bq_parameters=additional_bq_parameters, insert_retry_strategy=  RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR))
```

For this to work i needed to add window intervals (before write to big query)

```
pipeline = pipeline | "To Window Fixed Intervals" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(10)))
```

This windowed data then goes on to becomes input to 3 pipeline operations, 2 side inputs to `WriteToBigQuery` are like this -

```
table_name = (pipeline 
    | "Get table name" >> beam.Map(lambda record: get_table_name(record)) )
    table_name = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(table_name)

table_schema = (pipeline 
    | "Get table schema" >> beam.Map(lambda record: get_table_schema(record)) )
    table_schema = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(table_schema)
```

All of this was working fine untill i need to split the data before windowing intervals like

```
mapped_data = (pipeline 
    |"Converting to map ">>beam.ParDo(ConvertToMap()).with_outputs("SUCCESS","FAILURE"))
pipeline = (mapped_data['SUCCESS']
    | "To Window Fixed Intervals" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(10)))
```

As soon as i did this, i encountered following error -

```
( ValueError: PCollection of size 2 with more than one element accessed as a singleton view. First two elements encountered are "name_1", "name_1". [while running 'Writing to big query/_StreamToBigQuery/AppendDestination-ptransform-48']
```

I've skipped some steps from the pipeline as it was way too complex.

How can i fix this error?

I've tried using AsDict instead of AsSingleton but it gives following error -

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 20; 2 is required [while running 'Writing to big query/_StreamToBigQuery/AppendDestination-ptransform-48']
```

I don't think there is any usecase of AsDict here.
Maybe the issue was not due to tagging but it was just waiting to happen with high data as it is a streaming pipeline.

**Solution -**
The issue here was the side inputs were being generated every time but the main input was being generated only conditionally. This makes the number of side inputs more then the main inputs, hence the issue.

After fixing this issue but making side inputs generate through the same conditions as the main input, i've encountered another issue -

```
 Cannot convert GlobalWindow to apache_beam.utils.windowed_value._IntervalWindowBase [while running 'Writing to big query/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)-ptransform-124']
```

Adding these following windowing transforms to the pipeline

```
"Window into Global Intervals" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(1)) |beam.GroupByKey()
```

gave the following error -

```
AbstractComponentCoderImpl.encode_to_stream ValueError: Number of components does not match number of coders. [while running 'WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)
```

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Seems you have repeated keys, are you flattening SUCCESS and FAILURE and they might have overlapping keys? You can give it a try to `AsIter` instead of `AsSingleton`

Comment: @BrunoVolpato thanks for your response, i've updated the question as i have found a solution to this problem, but now i've encountered another issue.

Comment: Hi @Rorschach, can you try  the solution provided in this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705759) ? Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar, this does not work, it gives the error - `AbstractComponentCoderImpl.encode_to_stream ValueError: Number of components does not match number of coders. [while running 'WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)`

Comment: Hi @Rorschach, Can you try the code provided in this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767365/apache-beam-groupbykey-fails-when-running-on-google-dataflow-in-python)? Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs probably due to some issue with the code which is returning elements in GlobalWindow while the PCollection has a different window set. For your requirement, I would suggest you to insert  `beam.WindowInto(beam.window.GlobalWindows())`  between `beam.WindowInto(NONGLOBALWINDOW) | beam.GroupByKey()` and other Ptransform which causes problems.

Comment: Thanks for copy pasting the first answer that comes up when looking up this error, GlobalWindows won't as the error occurs when writing to big query.